# creating a joined matrix from a list of data in vba (like outer join)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2 columns that look like:

```
 field     group1
  a          1.2
  b          0.2
  c          2.4
field      group2
  a          0.2
  c          0.8
field      group3
 c           0.6
 d           0.8
```

and so forth. I have been pondering about this for a while but can't seem to find a good way.
Is there a efficient way to make the dataset look like:

```
field       group1       group2       group3
 a            1.2         0.2 
 b            0.2           
 c            2.4         0.8          0.6
 d                                     0.8
```

and so forth. Any help or idea?

Comment: Just put it in a pivot table, unselect the field identifiers (ie "group3" ) from the drop downs.

Comment: Ahhh, I missed that part, I normally just add one more column and use something like:  =IF(LEFT(D5,5)="Group",D5,E4) and then put it in a pivot table.  That will take the group name if there is one, if not copy the one above it.

Comment: =IF(UPPER(LEFT(D5,5))="GROUP",D5,E4) in case sometimes there is missed capitalization

Comment: i have added a macro below that does the necessary identification and transformations in memory that can be used repeatedly / large data sets. For a one-off you could alternatively use lookup formulae to find the closest group from above (in column c, stick in "=IF(ISTEXT(B1),ROW(),"")", then in d stick in "=INDEX($B$1:$B1,MATCH(MAX($C$1:$C1),$B$1:$B1,0)) dragged down). This will return the rows group name. Then apply a process with pivot tables etc, using the identified group name as a column header.

Comment: or rather than pivots, having got the column of group names per the formulae in my comment above, deduplicate them on another sheet and transpose them to get the column headers, then deduplicate the field names and stick them to the left of the column headers, then Index and Match wrapped in an IFERROR(__,"") to get the values at the intersection of each field (row) and group (column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a one-off, you can probably do it just with formulae to identify which groups a row is in and then pivot, as described by others in the comments to your question.

However, for repeated use / less hassle the below should work.

This works on your test data and outputs on a new sheet according to your desired output in the question.

It works in memory so it should have good performance when scaled up to thousands of cells.

```
Sub blah()

    'Declarations
    Dim outWs As Worksheet
    Dim inArr, outArr
    Dim vector(), groups()
    Dim outC As Collection
    Dim currentGroup As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim key

     'load data
    inArr = Selection.Value

    Set outC = New Collection

    'iterate through
    For i = LBound(inArr, 1) To UBound(inArr, 1)

        If inArr(i, LBound(inArr, 2)) Like "field*" Then 'new group

            currentGroup = currentGroup + 1
            ReDim Preserve groups(1 To currentGroup)
            groups(currentGroup) = inArr(i, LBound(inArr, 2) + 1) 'assign group name

        Else 'is a record/field

            key = inArr(i, LBound(inArr, 2))
            'retrieve existing, ignoring the exception thrown if key does not exist
            On Error Resume Next
            vector = outC(key)
            If Err.Number = 5 Then 'error raised when key does not exist
                ReDim vector(0 To currentGroup)
                vector(0) = key 'add key
            Else
                outC.Remove (key) 'the reference of item is immutable so we must remove and add again
                ReDim Preserve vector(0 To currentGroup) 'resize vector
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            vector(currentGroup) = inArr(i, LBound(inArr, 2) + 1) 'assign value to current group in vector
            outC.Add vector, key 'add to results
            Erase vector

        End If

    Next i

    'Process our results collection into an array suitable for dumping to a sheet
    ReDim outArr(1 To outC.Count, 1 To currentGroup + 1)
    For i = 1 To outC.Count
        For j = 0 To UBound(outC(i))
            outArr(i, j + LBound(outArr, 2) - LBound(outC(i))) = outC(i)(j)
        Next j
    Next i

    'dump data
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, 1 + UBound(groups))).Value = groups
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1 + UBound(outArr, 1), UBound(outArr, 2))).Value = outArr
    End With

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: @pnuts thanks. I repeated it just to show the input>output. But yeah - it wasnt necessary. I will remove it

Comment: wow that was a really fast execution too. Thanks. Time for me to actually go through what you did and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

so i have an idea, its not beautiful but it will probably work...
copy your whole field column and paste it to a fresh sheet, use data tab and hit remove duplicates, if you transpose that so your top row is Field, a, b, c, d you can drop a formula thats something like this (untested) "=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B, MATCH($B$1,Sheet1!A1:A3,0))"

the search range in match is intentionally small and left without $ to that if you drag this formula down it will search a little further(A2:A4,A3:A5,etc) once you get all of them just find/replace all the N/As remove blanks and your good

if i have time i will try and put together a little macro that would be a lot cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

In outline: Create a copy of your `group1` column, filter it for values greater than `0` and delete these. Fill the blanks with the respective groups and then pivot.

Answer (score 0):

i would rearrange data first, with a macro, this way:

```
Sub sa()
For Each cl In Range("B2:B1000").Cells
    If IsNumeric(cl.Value) And Not IsEmpty(cl.Value) Then
        If Not IsNumeric(cl.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Then
             cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = cl.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        Else
             cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = cl.Offset(-1, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

such that data would be rearranged with this column assignment:

```
[field] [value] [group]
```

then it would be easy to do what you want, just create a pivot table... tell me in the commentaries if in need of further help...